# Can not play Mordern Warfare Campaign without Warzone Update that locks Modern Warfare without buying XBox Live

Tags: xbox-one, call-of-duty-modern-warfare

My bother got my dad *Call of Duty Modern Warfare* for the XBox One. setting it up at first i skipped installing Multiplayer because my dad has no interest in it and he doesn't have internet access where he is. when trying to play the game it said in the top right it was 75% complete and Campaign wasn't available until full installation.

the following week i connected online and had to download a 97GB "update", when it was finally done after 2 days of downloading the launch screen said Warzone, when i get into the game it would want me to get XBox Live with 2 options for different ammounts, when i opt not to it complains about being unable to connect and when i choose to go offline i can't access Modern Warfare with it wanting me to go online, when i do i am presented with the same XBox Live purchase options.

i uninstalled Modern Warfare completely and reinstalled it this time including multi-player. while booting offline the Campaign is locked because it's not fully installed like last time but this time the top right is talking about an update (how it even knows there's one makes me think Microsoft lied about the XBox One needing to be online or it's a planned "day 1 patch" as a form of DRM). when i go online to get this update, it's a 97GB update which i assume is the one i just did before that forces me into Warzone and refuses to let me do anything unless i pay for XBox Live.

How can i play Call of Duty Modern Warfare campaign without the internet and needing xbox live subscription